# Using case on return value of subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'd like to write `case` clause which takes its input from inner query. Please let me describe this in more detail.

Say I have a table:

```
create table food
(   fruit varchar2(50),
    chips varchar2(50)
);
```

with values

```
INSERT INTO food
(fruit, chips)
VALUES ('Apple', 'Paprika');

INSERT INTO food
(fruit, chips)
VALUES ('Orange', 'Salt');
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b1e6f3812f771a33677f04559b9587b0)

I would like to write a query that will show:

fruit, chips and 1 if fruit is 'Apple' and 0 otherwise

which would give a result (example)

```
'Apple', 'Paprika', 1
'Orange, 'Salt', 0
```

I do not want use joins for this. **It has to be subquery**. That's a requirement I must comply with.

I've come up with the following query:

```
select f.fruit,
((case (select ff.fruit from food ff)
when ff.fruit = 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end ) as is_apple) from food f;
```

However, I get the following error `ORA-00905: missing keyword`

Comment: Why do you want to use subquery? I don't see any appropriate reasons.

Comment: @SuccessShrestha Please have a look at my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *it has to be subquery* then use `dual`:

```
select fruit, chips, 
      (select case food.fruit when 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end from dual) is_apple 
  from food;
```

or subselect from `food` using primary key (if your table contains it), or `rowid`:

```
select fruit, chips, 
      case (select fruit from food ff where ff.rowid = food.rowid) 
          when 'Apple' then 1 
          else 0 
      end is_apple 
  from food;
```

**<sub>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cca1ba2182b508eb50b4f501f75da5d6)</sub>**

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a subquery for this:

```
select fruit, chips,
       case when fruit = 'Apple'
         then 1
         else 0
       end as is_apple
from food
```

If the value must be the result of a subquery, you may use:

```
select fruit, chips,
       (select case when f2.fruit = 'Apple'
                 then 1
                 else 0
               end
        from food f2
        where f.rowid = f2.rowid
        )
from food f
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but subquery is a must - it is not for me for decide. I updated my post to reflect this need.